# Script to monitor and log folder size of multiple folder (Windows)

Tags: windows, size, directory, monitor

I'd like a script that'll monitor folder1, folder2, folder3 and create a log with their combined size, for Windows.

Would it be possible to do this with a .bat file or something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean a script that continously monitors folders or one that is able to collect the information once? Possibly I would recommend a stronger scripting facility than batch files - perhaps Python (http://www.python.org).

Comment: A script that I could run manually whenver needed would do. I have very poor programming knowledge, which is why I limit myself to something I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying (and removing a few debug statements) from here: http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/MS-DOS/382631/382631/dos-commandbatch-file-to-find-a-folder-size/

```
@For /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('"dir folder* /s /-c | find "bytes" | find /v "free""') do @Set summaryout=%%a
@For /f "tokens=1,2 delims=)" %%a in ("%summaryout%") do @set filesout=%%a&set sizeout=%%b
@Set sizeout=%sizeout:bytes=%
@Set sizeout=%sizeout: =%
@Echo Size is :%sizeout%
```

You might have to change this a bit, for I considered the folders (as you specified) are similarly named.

Comment: That worked pretty nicely. My folders are located with unique names on 3 different drives. How would I solve that?

Comment: @habitats: You could create a another batch file that calls this one (sort of like a function-call) with the single argument a foldername.